# Excel VBA Userform If Focus Changes Trigger

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a couple user forms in VBA, id like to add a feature that when a user first clicks on a textbox (changes the focus to it), any text inside gets selected. I've seen this feature in some accounting applications and in your web browser when you first click the URL bar. Its essentially meant so that users can immediately overwrite a text field. Was wondering how I might do the same in VBA, but I'm still a novice. I looked through a couple sub triggers(dont know the correct term) but haven't seen any. I found one for when you click the text box but I don't want the text constantly being selected every time I click the field. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have thus far?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to start this, I see a Setfocus command, but no IsItFocused. And I see a DblClick and MouseDown private sub for textbox1 but I don't see any subs for Focused or SingleClick. any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your textbox event

```
Dim checked As Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If checked = True Then
        TextBox1.SelStart = 0
        TextBox1.SelLength = 0
    checked = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    checked = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If checked = False Then
        TextBox1.SelStart = 0
        TextBox1.SelLength = Len(TextBox1)
        checked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

once you click your textbox, it will hightlight the text, if you click the text, it will unhightlight and allow you to modified the text. if you click outside that textbox and click back inside that will rehighlight the whole text.

Comment: Pretty good, lolz can't believe that was only two lines; however, it doesn't deselect if I double click. it will deselect if I double click on the last character in the textbox, but won't deselect if I double click in the middle. is there a work-around for that?

Comment: just use arrow key to move to desire spot in text.

Comment: @pokemin_Man ikr, makes sense to you and me but it won't it to make sense to others. you end up getting other people yelling at you for making them work anything more than the initial mouse click. I don't even know if excel is able to do these kinda things. thanks.

Comment: @benmazor tell them either use this or you will have to double click the text in the textbox to override/delete it ect.

Comment: sorry, it's only a partial solution. I did say in my question that I don't want the text box to stay constantly selected after the first click. ill give you a check I guess until something better comes.